# Codesign error ,What can I do?

Tags: iphone

When I debug my application on device,it alert the info "
Codesign error: no certificate was found in your keychain for the specified identifier "(null)"

Comment: Is this the first time you do this? Or does it work for other projects?

Answer (score 0):

You may not have an application identifier set. Make sure that in your Target Settings > Properties, you have a valid reverse DNS identifier (com.apple.myapp, for example) entered into your Identifier field. Also make sure your Code Signing Identity is set to the correct certificate (Target Settings > Build).